# Is there a way to use ROW_NUMBER() and keep the numeration with same identifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table.

| NumRegOper | nReg |
| --- | --- |
| 2067914121937973 | 1 |
| 2074206165945447 | 2 |
| 2074206165945447 | 3 |
| 2067914121937973 | 4 |
| 2074206165945098 | 5 |

If I use this script:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by NumRegOper desc) as NewOrder
    , *
from #tmp
```

I got this result:

| NewOrder | NumRegOper | nReg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2074206165945447 | 2 |
| 2 | 2074206165945447 | 3 |
| 3 | 2074206165945098 | 5 |
| 4 | 2067914121937973 | 1 |
| 5 | 2067914121937973 | 4 |

But what I want is that keeps the same 'NewOrder' when its the same NumRegOper identifier. Like this:

| NewOrder | NumRegOper | nReg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2074206165945447 | 2 |
| 1 | 2074206165945447 | 3 |
| 2 | 2074206165945098 | 5 |
| 3 | 2067914121937973 | 1 |
| 3 | 2067914121937973 | 4 |

There is a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Use dense_rank() rather than row_number()

Comment: You are a life saver John! please make it an answer to select it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Cappelletti says in the comments the following will give you the desired result:

```
 select  DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by NumRegOper desc) as NewOrder ,* from #tmp
```